# Executing command with rt.exec (mysql load data) on linux

Tags: java, mysql, linux

I am getting problem on executing the following code:

```
  Process pr = rt.exec("mysql -uroot -pcdac123 -e \""
              + "use rrrlfdev;load data local infile '"
              + fpath
              + "' into table t_adm_despatch fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\\\"' lines terminated by '\\n'  (dispatchno,dispatchdate,dispatchName, dispatchAddress, fileNo)"
              + "\"");
```

The same is running fine on windows.

Comment: What is the problem..?, If u getting any error then put it also.

Comment: It is showing mysql help file.... internal query is not executing...

Answer (score 0):

Java needs to know command and arguments separately. You can do 2 things

1) You can try to use exec(String command, String[] arguments) to provide the cmd and the args seperately

2) You can enclose the mysql command and each argument into double quotes.

In your case, error is misplacement of quotes starting. There is no such command like

mysql -uroot -pcdac123 -e \" .....

This is the reason it shows help file. Double quotes should be placed after mysql command, like

mysql \" -uroot -pcdac123 -e .....

Hope this will help

Comment: The same thing is running fine on windows. The command is not mysql -uroot -pcdac123 -e \" but  mysql -uroot -pcdac123 -e "use rrrlfdev.. \ acts as an escape character for double quotes. I printed the command in console and it is running fine if I put it directly on linux terminal. I will try to separate arguments, but I don't know why it is running fine on windows, but not on linux.